# UIInterfaceOrientation in UINavigationViewController

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm having issue with auto rotating in my view which is inside a UINavitionViewController and the navigationViewcontroller is inside a tabBarViewController.

I subclassed tabBarViewController. The problem is the interfaceorientation works fine on the first view inside the tabViewController, but whenever I push to another view it doesn't work.

This is a code in subclass tabBarController

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
    if([self.selectedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]){
        return [[(UINavigationController*)self.selectedViewController visibleViewController] shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
    } else {
        return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think your function will always return YES?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a `UIViewController` inside a `UINavigationController` inside a `UITabBarController`. The rotation is decided by `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in your `UIViewController`. You need to override that method for every `UIViewController` to return the desired value, i.e., `YES` if you want it to rotate and `NO` if you don't want it to.

You shouldn't override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in `UINavigationController` or `UITabBarController`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: in the view controllers for all the views in the tab bar.

If a view controller's shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: returns NO, then the tab bar will not rotate, even if the view is hidden at the time of the rotation.